# Как отсортировать многомерный (2 уровня) массив по одному из элементов, по возр.. Но если у дочернего отсутствует элемент, то он встал в конец

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Вот, есть такой массив

```
 $material_weights = array(

    0 => array(
        'nid' => 54545,
        'weight' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
        'nid' => 545,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'nid' => 225,
        'weight' => 4
    ),
    3 => array(
        'nid' => 6,
        'weight' => 1
    ),
    4=> array(
        'nid' => 6,
    ),
    5 => array(
        'nid' => 6,
        'weight' => 3
    ),
)
```

Нужно отсортировать его по полю 'weight', по возрастанию, так чтобы все элементы у которых, нет поля 'weight', поставились в конец. Но лучше, чтобы сохранили свою первоначальную последовательность, то есть 1 и 6 элементы должны вставить в конец, но 1 все так же должен идти перед 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если порядок элементов у которых нет поля 'weight' не важен:

```
usort($material_weights, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['weight'] ?? null) <=> ($b['weight'] ?? null);
});
```

Если важно сохранить порядок следования:

```
//array_filter сохраняет ключи
$have_not_weight = array_filter($material_weights, function($val) {
    return !isset($val['weight']);
});

$material_weights = array_diff_key($material_weights, $have_not_weight);

usort($material_weights, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['weight'] ?? null) <=> ($b['weight'] ?? null);
});

$material_weights = array_merge($material_weights, $have_not_weight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну как то так наверно -

```
usort($material_weights, function($a, $b) {
    if(isset($a['weight'])&&isset($b['weight'])) {
         return $a['weight'] <=> $b['weight']; // return $a['weight'] - $b['weight'];
    } elseif(!isset($a['weight'])) {
         return 1;
    } elseif(!isset($b['weight'])) {
         return -1;
    }
});
```

вторую часть вопроса не понял.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 54545
        [weight] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 6
        [weight] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 6
        [weight] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 225
        [weight] => 4
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 6
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [nid] => 545
    )

)
```

Comment: Ошибся. Имелось в виду, что те элементы,  у которых нет weight должны не просто встать в конец, а остаться в той же очередности, то есть элементы с индексом 1и 4 должны быть в самом конце, но элемент у которого был индекс 1 все так же должен быть перед элементом с индексом 4. Ваш ответ почти то что надо, только бывший 4 стоит перед бывшим 1

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ, это пройтись по всему массиву и сортировать элементы по вашей необходимости. В случае, если элемент массива не содержит `weight`, то вырезать этот элемент в новый массив `array1`и так, пройтись до самого конца ващего текущего массива. Когда все элементы будут отсортированы, то всё содержимое из `array1` вернуть обратно в `array`.

Можно всё сделать без второго массива используя несколько `if-else`

Comment: Предложите ответ?) пока не даже собственную сортировку не понимаю как сделать. а уж чтобы вырезать и вставить обратно...

Comment: Я с php вообще не знаком) Зато я вижу алгоритм, по которому это можно сделать. Его я вам написал выше. И, немного поиска по вашей теме дают 2 отличных примера, таких как [этот](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/) и  [этот](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php)